# Does altitude play a role in the strength of electric fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electricity, electric-fields

After many controlled trials, I can conclude that the same device - e.g. a monitor - will emit far higher electric fields upstairs than downstairs, from the same distance, and in environments that almost exactly mirror one another.

The only things I have not yet ruled out are:

- an altitude effect (potentially on the meter as well)
- something to do with the wiring of the house (multiple surge protectors show green lights for 'Grounded', for what it's worth)

I have also controlled for electromagnetic interference and 'dirty electricity'. I am getting readings of up to 500% higher simply by moving the device upstairs.

Comment: The electric field depends on the charges distribution between your recording instrument and *infinite* in all directions.

It looks like the charge distribution in your monitor is the same, but not in the surrounding. For example, it may be that the soil is conductive and that your downstairs is conductive, while upstairs the room floor is all made of reinforced concrete, so you have some kind of Faraday cage.

Comment: Details on how you are measuring and with what would be helpful. What is controlling for ‘dirty electricity’ mean?

Comment: What kind of equipment are you using to measure electric fields, and what section are you measuring on the test devices?

Comment: Can you reproduce your measurements elsewhere?